# Open only .xml file in JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am developing a java application for which I need only `.xml` files. Now I want to show only `.xml` files in `JFileChooser` whenever user wants to save a file or open a existing file.

Is this possible to show only `.xml` files?

Comment: See [JFile chooser window?? How do I filter files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876841/jfile-chooser-window-how-do-i-filter-files)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use JFileChooser API to achieve your task.

For  Open only .xml file

```
// create a filechooser;
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(cwd);
FileNameExtensionFilter xmlfilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
     "xml files (*.xml)", "xml");

chooser.setDialogTitle("Open schedule file");
// set selected filter
chooser.setFileFilter(xmlfilter);
```

Also, go through  javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter.

Comment: I have edited my post check it, sFilter is for sdfFilter if you want use it and for that we need to create sdfFilter like xmlFilter

Answer (score 3):

If I remember right, you should use addChoosableFileFilter or setFileFilter method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#addChoosableFileFilter(javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter)