# Show only TSTA* files in JFileChooser

Tags: java, linux, jfilechooser, rhel

So, inverse to the question: [Open only .xml file in JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596468/open-only-xml-file-in-jfilechooser)

I'd like to open a `JFileChooser` that shows files starting with, for example, `"TSTA"`. I don't care about the rest of the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always implement your own [`FileFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html):

```
public class TSTAFileFilter extends FileFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        return f.getName().startsWith("TSTA");
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Only files starting with TSTA";
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(cwd);
TSTAFileFilter filter = new TSTAFileFilter();
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
```